# Angular ngModel with dynamic parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

In this Angular example, the ngModel binding does not work.
Can  someone let me understand why? and if so, What is the best way to do it?

(note that the binding uses a dynamic key)

**ts:**

```
constructor() {  this.days = { day1:'data', day2:'data2', day3:'data3...' }}
```

**html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
   <span> {{days['day'+i]}}</span>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="days['day'+i]" />
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I checked the above code and it is running correctly.

Comment: I am not getting any error, but the input value is empty. I do not see the 'data' and 'data2' etc.

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule`?

Comment: Sure. 
In your POC does it work as expected?

Comment: You can check the stackblitz link I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngModel binding is not working because the ngFor directive creates a new scope for each iteration, and the days object is not being updated correctly within that scope.

To fix this issue, you can use an array to store the values for each day instead of using a dynamic key.

```
constructor() {
  this.days = ['data', 'data2', 'data3'];
}

<div *ngFor="let day of days; let i=index">
  <span> {{day}}</span>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="days[i]" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might missed importing `FormsModule`

Check this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahcs6h?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the FormsModule module into your Angular app

```
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```